# Javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I have tried numerous pieces of JavaScript in my simple HTML file. However, none of them work. I am using Adobe Dreamweaver CS4 and have tried using both Safari and Firefox browsers

I've also done some tests, and JavaScript is enabled in both browsers. The problem is within my page or Dreamweaver. Could anyone give me some suggestions to find the issue?

This is an example of the code I'm trying to use.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/facebook" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

I placed the first part just under my  tag and the second part in a table in the body.

Comment: Please post the code you're having problems with.

Comment: "Won't work" is useless diagnostic information. See [http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Are you running it locally with a `file:///` URI scheme? Protocol-less URLs will not work in that case.

Comment: Yes Fabrício i'm running it locally, would i need to upload my site to a webserver to test it?

Comment: Just add `http://` as the protocol: `http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1`. I'll write up an answer with more detail meanwhile.

Comment: Oh yeah, FB won't load on a page loaded through the `file:///` scheme, but it should work just fine on a live server or a localhost web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that protocol-less URLs inherit the protocol used to open the current document, that is, they usually do not work with the `file:///` URI scheme.

To test locally without such problems, install a local web server - [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) - and run the local files through the `http://` protocol. Alternatively, you can upload it to your webserver for testing as well.

Side-note: FB won't load using the `file:///`, it needs to be loaded on a web server (a localhost one will work as well).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/MWAZY/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, **but you can't test locally because of security reason.**

The double slash is good without the **http:**

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

new protocols acts likes that.

Look this fiddle, It's exactly the same as you have in your code, but not being in *local* if it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/h4xgn/